# C# Find Like Strings In Array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, compare, string-comparison

Question:
I have a array of strings and I am trying to find the closest match to a provided string. I have made a few attempts below as well as checking into some other solutions such as Levenshtein Distance which seems to only work if all the strings are of similar sizes.

Expetation:
If I were to use "two are better" as the match string is that it would match with "Two are better than one".

Thought:
I was wondering if breaking apart the stringToMatch string where there are spaces and then seeing if each of those parts of the stringToMatch string are found in the current iteration of the array ( arrayOfStrings[i] ) would be helpful at all?

```
// Test array and string to search
string[] arrayOfStrings = new string[] { "A hot potato", "Two are better than one", "Best of both worlds", "Curiosity killed the cat", "Devil's Advocate", "It takes two to tango", "a twofer" };
string stringToMatch = "two are better";


// Contains attempt
List<string> likeNames = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.Count(); i++)
{
    if (arrayOfStrings[i].Contains(stringToMatch))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hit1");
        likeNames.Add(arrayOfStrings[i]);                    
    }

    if (stringToMatch.Contains(arrayOfStrings[i]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hit2");
        likeNames.Add(arrayOfStrings[i]);
    }
}


// StringComparison attempt
var matches = arrayOfStrings.Where(s => s.Equals(stringToMatch, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();



// Display matched array items
Console.WriteLine("List likeNames");
likeNames.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

Console.WriteLine("\n");

Console.WriteLine("var matches");
matches.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: So you want a string distance algorithm that works well with different length strings and that helps you better determine( or gives a closer score) if one of them is a sub-string?... This is not really a good fit for stackoverflow. There are umpteen different string distance algorithms that do many different things for different reasons . Maybe you need to look a bit closer at what each of them do and research the comparisons that are available between them.. i say this because there are so many desired outcomes here that aren't evident in your question and really is unanswerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code.

> I have created `List<string>` based on your `stringToMatch` and checked if strings in `array` of `strings` contains every string present in `toMatch`, if yes then selected that string into `match`.

```
List<string> toMatch = stringToMatch.Split(' ').ToList();
List<string> match = arrayOfStrings.Where(x => 
                                   !toMatch.Any(ele => !x.ToLower()
                                   .Contains(ele.ToLower())))
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: This works pretty well when trying to match parts of the string separated at the spaces. I combined this with Levenshtein's method to give a backup option in case the user misspelled all sub sections of the string he entered. Thanks for posting!

Comment: @Pie happy to help

Answer (score -1):

For your implementation, I have split the stringToMatch and then took the count for matchings.

The below code will give you Order list with count with ordered with Highest string match count.

```
string[] arrayOfStrings = new string[] { "A hot potato", "Two are better than one", "Best of both worlds", "Curiosity killed the cat", "Devil's Advocate", "It takes two to tango", "a twofer" };
            string stringToMatch = "two are better";

            var matches = arrayOfStrings
                  .Select(s =>
                  {
                      int count = 0;
                      foreach (var item in stringToMatch.Split(' '))
                      {
                          if (s.Contains(item))
                              count++;
                      }
                      return new { count, s };
                  }).OrderByDescending(d => d.count);
```

I have used very simple string comparison to verify. The algorithm can vary as per exact requirement(Like sequence of matching string, etc)